# Is "Have we a menu?" a correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is this a correct sentence?

> Have we a menu?

It sounds a little bit strange to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Have we" is an idiom most familiar to British English, interchangeable with "do we have".  It may sound strange to some speakers, but I would not go so far as to call it incorrect, reading the "do" as implied.

Comment: If 'have we [...]' is said with a British accent, it sounds OK. Posh, but not ungrammatical. If it's said with any other accent, it just sounds totally incorrect. Moral of the story: if in doubt, just say "do we have [...]".

Comment: At the very least, someone using the idiom who does not speak with a British accent makes an impression that they're trying to come across posh by sounding British.

Comment: As someone brought up on fairly ‘high’ BrE, this example sounds slightly awkward to me.  I couldn’t quite put my finger on why, but it’s not a case where I’d expect this inversion — I can imagine my mother asking “Have we any lemons?”, but not “Have we a menu?”.  Generally I’d agree with @chaos, though: this certainly isn’t incorrect, though it might sound a bit stilted.

Comment: Reminds me of the priest's line in _The Princess Bride_, "Have you . . . the wing?" I know subject-verb inversions in declarative senteces should usually be avoided. As Bryan A. Garner argues, "Inversions are probably intended to signal emphasis, but in fact they often convey preciosity" (and, I would add, a distinct Yoda-esque quality). Inversions in questions make sense more often, but this example still sounds stilted.

Comment: Semantically, "Have we a menu" matches perfectly with accepted grammar in Dutch and German.  I suspect that this form, used in English, is a left over from the common parent-language.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct; however, the style is affected, so it's really not a construction I'd suggest to anyone unless they are native speakers writing something in which an affected tone is useful.